# Easiest way to scope / filter string Ruby data with range slider

Tags: ruby, search, scope

I have a light search engine I'm trying to build out.   One of the search requirements is a slider range,  0-10 based on a persons experience.

In the User attribute experience we store 5 strings (0-1, 2-3, 4-5, 6-8, 10+)

I've been using ruby scopes in the model for the other attributes, but what is a good solution for filtering on a range of string data like this?

So for example if the end user selects the slider from 1-8,  it would display all user records that have this attribute marked with (0-1, 2-3, 4-5, 6-8) and not render any users with 10+

Comment: can you show what you have attempted already?

Comment: I've only attempted a scope such as  scope :salary,    -> (salary) { where minimum_salary: salary },  but this clearly won't work on the above since I'll be provided 2 integers, and based on that need to filter

Comment: `1-8` includes `0-1`? Isn't zero under the range? How would a `1-6` behave? will it include `6-8`?

Comment: Yeah well this is the main problem, perhaps I shouldn't be storing this data in 1 string attribute.  Maybe there should be 2 integer values instead, which might make filtering easier for a slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the strings to actual numbers and store the actual numbers in the db instead of (or even as well as) strings.

In this case: (0-1, 2-3, 4-5, 6-8, 10+) maps nicely onto the numbers 1-5

Then you can use > < in SQL quite easily.

eg slider '1-8' converts to SQL of `the_column >= 0 AND the_column <= 4`